Code after Task is happening before the code inside finishes, despite await
I have the following method that gets an IEnumerable and runs a different function on each value there in parallel. However, I noticed when placing breakpoints that the code outside of the Task is happening before the code inside is, despite the await. What do I need to be doing differently so the code runs as expected?
BulkStatusQueryMessage is a class that contains a referenceId and an IEnumerable of an inner class that has id and OriginalRequestReferenceId
private async Task<BulkResults> GetStatus(BulkStatusQueryMessage bulkStatusQueryMessage)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<Results>();

    await Task.Run(async () => Parallel.ForEach(bulkStatusQueryMessage.StatusQueries, async sq =>
    {
        try
        {
            var res = await _apiMethods.SendApiGetCall(ApiCallType.Status,
                queryParameters: sq.Id);
            var result =
                ExtractResultsFromResponse(res.Response, sq.OriginalRequestReferenceId);
            results.Add(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to get status for id {sq.id}"
                + $" with OriginalRequestReferenceId {sq.OriginalRequestReferenceId}");
        }
    }));

    return new BulkResults
    {
        ReferenceId = bulkStatusQueryMessage.ReferenceId,
        Responses = results
    };
}

What I am experiencing is that when debugging, if an exception is thrown from _apiMethods.SendApiGetCall, I first get to the line with the return and only later get to the line with the catch. I am not understanding why this is happening or what I need to do differently so the code would first complete everything within the lambda and only then go to the lines outside the Task.Run.

Use await Parallel.ForEachAsync instead of Task.Run(()=>Parallel.ForEach. What you did is a major bug.

You've been beaten by Parallel.ForEach's unfriendliness for async/await. You are not the first one. Fortunately there are many solutions available for this problem.

Parallel.ForEach  has no overloads that accept a Func<Task> so async sq creates a delegate whose signature is async void Something(SomeType sq). async void calls that can't be awaited. The question's code fires off lots of tasks and never waits for them to complete

@ Panagiotis Kanavos Parallel.ForEachAsync gives me the error CS0117 'Parallel' does not contain a definition for 'ForEachAsync' - what am I missing?

Most likely you are targeting a .NET version earlier than .NET 6. You can find here a Parallel.ForEachAsync implementation for older versions and platforms.
